# A pointer to "how to post a test case with any Oracle SQL or PL/SQL question"

Tags: discussion, questions, tag-wiki, question-quality

I see a lot of users posting a new question related to Oracle SQL or PL/SQL, do not post a working test case.

A good question related to Oracle SQL or PL/SQL should include a working test case. For me, a working test case include the basic(minimum) steps to reproduce/replicate OP's scenario.

I am not sure if such a thing already exists, else we could have it.

For example, http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Test_case

Comment: Put one in the [Oracle tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info).

Comment: Seems a good idea. I thought to do so when I edited the wiki last time. I just hope others would agree too.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Oracle and an endemic problem throughout SO; downvote, vote to close, comment to explain how to describe a problem to strangers, or all 3. Just don't do nothing if you have the reputation to do something.