# Can Stack Overflow allow a working database for SQL questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I'd like to answer more SQL questions, but it is hard to do so without the ability to test.  And it is pretty laborious for me to create a database to answer a single question.  I'm aware there's SQL Fiddle, but it would be good if SO could allow some method of creating a database in the question to allow the questioner to either create a database of sorts in the question or give the person answering the question a way to better help them.

Is the only answer for the user to put in their `Create` statements?

[Questions involving database queries - can we make it easier for people to create well-formatted data for testing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298973/questions-involving-database-queries-can-we-make-it-easier-for-people-to-creat)

Comment: I got a downvote in less that 57 seconds.  New record for me.

Comment: Heh. We're dedicated like that.

Comment: Yes, it is very encouraging.

Comment: It only means we disagree with your feature request, nothing more.

Comment: Well, you are aware of the only proper answer already: Create-statements and the like to create a database with the proper layout and contents, if needed. That's part of creating an MCVE.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I guess that's different from the regular SO questions, then.  I was not aware.

Comment: @Deduplicator I hate to ask this, but what is MCVE?

Comment: Well, if this was on main I would have linked it like this: [mcve] Anyway, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I has a sad because of that question :( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313675/help-center-search-for-mcve-does-not-return-the-mcve-help-page

Comment: Did you know about http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? I never used it, but it may help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As someone who has answered a lot of [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) questions on the site, I wish this was something that was implemented, but it's not feasible.

There are external tools that can be used to do this including:

- [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)
- [Stack Exchange Data Explorer aka SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

and probably others. These will allow you to create tables, run queries, etc. and then you can post a link to it inside your answer.

Creating servers to run a variety of RDBMS platforms is not something we're able to do at this time, so this is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Answer (score 10):

It's too complex to expect Stack Overflow to supply an entire DBMS for a question or two.  Here are some reasons I can think of off the top of my head:

- The specific version of their DBMS may be proprietary
- The specific version may be difficult or cumbersome to install
- There may be specific configuration settings or tuning that would impact the result of the query or its performance

Notwithstanding that [I too agree that the OP needs to supply the data as part of their question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299041/1079354), asking Stack Overflow to supply a blank database would be too much of a lift.  If you want to answer the question but you don't have the right DBMS to answer it with, be *very* careful about that as you may be rightfully called out for having bad SQL syntax or performance.

Comment: Don't take this wrong.  I don't know how to ask it, but how do you (or anyone) know it would too much of a lift?  I thought SO guys could do anything.

Comment: I'm not speaking as anyone that even comes remotely close to working for Stack Exchange, but if I were working there, I'd think it'd be a bit much for right now.  All things considered, there are a lot of other conditions, states, configurations, and the like that would make setting up a test database that requires that fairly complex.  Besides, I still feel like if you want help with your database against a specific set of data, **you should provide the specific set of data.**

Comment: I'm not suggesting they don't provide the data.  I'm suggesting SO provide the mechanism to provide the data.  The data is usually presented.  It's not presented in a way I can test it unless the SQL Create statements are given.

Comment: In that case, and at that instant, this is a failing of the OP to provide enough context to answer the question.  If they don't include their data, their question should be put on hold until they do so.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the whole idea seems preposterous to me.  Such systems cannot be tested/debugged/whatever on a Q&A blog.  Any question that appeared with 'real' datasets and tables appended I would immediately close as 'too broad'.

Comment: @MartinJames:  It's not unrealistic to assume that there is more than one person running a copy of Access...and besides, if it *can* be answered with what's presented in the question, there's no reason to close it.