# Better support for sample data and perhaps table schemas in SQL questions

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown, formatting

I've been around SO since almost the beginning, and in that time I've answered a [LOT](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3043%20%5Bsql%5D%20or%20%5Bsql-server%5D) of SQL related questions. One point of pain in this area has always been posting sample data or query results. We've had to use ascii table formatting in `<pre>` blocks or indented for code blocks, with further tricks to keep syntax highlighting from doing weird things. This is tedious and slow to do, both for askers and answerers.

This was [asked about and declined previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables). Many more times than that, I'm sure. But that was back in 2010. And for nearly 8 years now I've been content to leave it at that.

I'm bringing this up again because I've experienced a disturbing trend where it seems that questions increasingly include a screen-capture from sqlPlus or Management Studio, rather than real sample data. I've noticed this more in other areas, too, and we may want to think about treating images in posts as a potential signal for low-quality generally, as well as a way to address that... but for the moment I want to think about SQL questions.

*We could really use an easier method for getting sample data or results into Stack Overflow in a nice tabular or DDL/DML format that is easier for new users to discover.* Preferably something that also wraps properly on the mobile app. Ideally the ability to copy/paste from the common query tools... perhaps a "paste data" button on the toolbar that evaluated the clipboard contents to create a nice table.

This isn't a new request, but I believe it is something that has sat idle for a while and may deserve a new look.

Comment: Side note: the time frame for the post in that link made me realize we are rapidly approaching SO's 10th anniversary!

Comment: Sigh... once again the victim of search fail. I did look, but more research **after** I post (of course) finds this request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298973/questions-involving-database-queries-can-we-make-it-easier-for-people-to-creat?rq=1

Comment: I am for anything that reduces the number of screenshots of text.

Comment: In fairness, that other request is asking for a lot more. I don't know that a  full "CREATE TABLE" is necessarily a good idea, since not all DBMS have the same syntax here.

Comment: @BSMP The sad thing is I don't know if this will actually help much, because I've also seen so many posts with code images in recent months in other tag areas, too. But this does address a pain point.

Comment: When Q&A *finally* switches to CommonMark, this will be possible.

Comment: @Stijn I didn't think CommonMark had any native table support. I  assumed we'd need something to help build the ascii table/pre blocks automatically from tab or comma-delimited source data on the clipboard. What blocker in MarkDown does CommonMark relieve?

Comment: It doesn't by default, but it allows for extensions. [The CommonMark parser that was used for Docs supports tables](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/19091), and Q&A is supposed to switch to that parser at some point.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238957/will-commonmark-be-adopted-for-se

Comment: @BSMP i also [dislike screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/57475)

Comment: Just linking: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) as it seems loosely related to asking a good SQL question.

Comment: I think this a great idea as with the traffic of SQL questions (currently 435,144) with a lot of them needing/providing sample data in the form of code text which the formatting could screw up to then be a long process fixing it or screenshots of data which some people might not be able to view, would make these questions a lot more useful which is the aim here really

Comment: Not just SQL questions, obviously. Whenever an Excel spreadsheet problem [could be solved with an SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13911760/111794) against the Excel data, having the sample data makes it much easier to build said statement.

Comment: Just a thought: if we could have explicitly marked sample data sections, should matches in sample data be excluded from search engine results?

Comment: I find sqlfiddle.com etc. useful for complex sample data. It's easy to generate and people can use it to find/test a solution.

Comment: While there are many tools (rextester, sqlfiddle and such), I'd really like to have this on-site. Some RDBMSes have no support for bulk inserts or multiple statements, and don't have these testing tools. Having tables on-site would help a lot imo.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir And when SqlFiddle goes down (which it does regularly, what do we do?

Comment: Please do not encourage people to post their sample data in a tabular way. I too answer a lot of SQL questions (though for a shorter period of time), and share your frustration. However, Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) (this is a part of one of my regular comments on SQL questions) - Perhaps it's better to think of a way to incorporate automatic generation of dml+ddl from tabular data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I tried to write a [simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491717/) (10k+) i could reference for people that weren't providing DDL / DML to show them how they could provide better questions, but [folks weren't too keen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357257) on my approach to adding a post like that, even though I had good intentions, so I ended up deleting it. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) is a good reference, but I feel it's just way too long to expect users to read and digest.

Comment: @Tanner I actually like your deleted question, though I think sending people to read it all might result in frustrated people that are reluctant to ask questions on SO at all - for the simple reason that it's quite long. Personally, I keep in a comment on my SO profile a few generic comments (like the one I've pasted a part of in my previous comment) and just paste them when I think they can help.

Comment: @ZoharPeled like you i just got fed up with folks that weren't posting examples that would help them get better / quicker answers. When i wrote that Q&A it started as a simple exercise to give users an example, but then i kept adding more info that I thought was useful, but yeh, i get what you mean about it's length.